# Can't access $_GET after rewrite

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here's the mod_rewrite portion of my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase  /

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ web/$2?w=$1 [QSA]
```

What this does is, if someone visits http://example.com/webname/
the URL that is really processed is
http://example.com/web/index.php?w=id

Now, if I try to pass an extra random **GET** parameter to my rewritten **URL**, the parameter is ignored. So if I try to do visit here:

`index.php?page=page_id`

The parameter `page` is ignored. It doesn't seem to get passed at all.

Can this problem be fixed? If so, how?

Comment: `index.php` does not match your RewriteRule you are not allowing `.`

Comment: so how can I allow dots? how to fix it?

Comment: google is your friend: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be using this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase  /

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ web/index.php?w=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w.-]+)/?$ web/$2?$1=1 [QSA,L]
```

This will let you use pretty URLs as either of:

```
http://example.com/welcome
http://example.com/welcome?page=page_id
```

Comment: example.com/{the_username}/index.php?template={temp_name}&id={page_id}

Comment: What is exact URL you want to show in browser and what should be internal URL for the same?

Comment: the real url is:
http://example.com/web/index.php?username=1&temp=page&page_id=1
I want it to be:
http://example.com/username/index.php?temp=page&page_id=1